# Rebuild select menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I rebuilt a select menu with jQuery Mobile?

Here is my code...

```
<script>
$(document).delegate('#registration-city', 'pageinit', function () {
    // $("#city").selectmenu('refresh', true); //Rebuild is don't work
    $("#zip").change(function () {
        // $("#city").selectmenu('refresh', true); //Rebuild is don't work
        ...
        $('#city').append(response.list).selectmenu('refresh'); // Works
        ...
        });
    $("#zip").keyup(function () {
    ...
        $("#city").selectmenu('refresh', true); // Rebuild is don't work
    ...
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the `create` event on the dynamically inserted elements in JQM

```
  $("#elementid").trigger("create");
```

Comment: So I solve my problem with _empty()_ ...`$("#zip").keyup(function () { $('#city').empty(); $("#city").selectmenu('refresh', true);});` Now I wonder if `trigger("create")` is necessary. ^^